# Undefined reference to a function defined by me

Tags: reference, undefined

When I call `readTransition()` function in `readDPDA()` function declaration I get `linker error: undefined reference`.
How can I use a function defined by me in another function's declaration ?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 void readTransitionRules(char * temp);
 void readDPDA(char * filename);
int main()
{
  // irrelevant
}

 void readTransitionRules(char * temp)
 {
char *tempToken;
tempToken=strtok(temp," ,:");
int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("%s",tempToken);
    strtok(NULL," ,:");
 }
   }
 void readDPDA(char * filename)
 {
/*This function tries to open DPDA text file to read
states,alphabet,stack symbols and transition rules
of the DPDA that we will use as Word Checker.     */
extern void readTransitionRules(char * temp);

char * temp;

FILE * readerForDPDA;
readerForDPDA = fopen(filename,"r");
if(readerForDPDA!=NULL)
{
    fgets(temp,30,readerForDPDA);
    if(temp[0]=='T')
    {
        readTransitionRule(temp);
    }
}
else
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `readTransitionRule`, but your function is named `readTransitionRules`.

You probably had a warning about implicit function declaration. Don't ignore warnings.

Comment: Thanks @zch,
Actually yes i had that warning but i thought i was doing something wrong with something else.This code was not in main.c but another .c file.Thought error was related to that.

Answer (score 0):

In `ReadDPDA` you refer to a `readTransitionRule` and not a `readTransitionRules` as you have defined. You are missing the letter `s`.

Comment: Thanks for your input.I think i was blinded at that moment.